# mongo cursor s3 putObject

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-s3, pymongo

I am trying to query mongodb documents using Pymongo and trying to write them to s3. I want to save files to s3 in json array format. I can restore it back to mongo easily. Mongodb queries are getting build dynamically and I dont have option to save documents at some temporary location and then upload .

Below snippet works but it consumes lot of memory. To copy 1.5GB data it consumes ~12GB of physical memory.

```
mongo_query = {"$and": [{"ABC": school_year_id.upper()}, {"XYZ": clientid}]
        plans = mongo_conn[self.database][self.collection]
        plans_archivable_docs = plans.find(mongo_query)
        s3_key = school_year + '/' + clientid + '/' + self.database + self.collection + '.json'
        s3_client = mngarchs3.get_s3_client()
        response = s3_client.put_object(ACL='private',
                                        Bucket='xxxx-mongo-archives',
                                        Key=s3_key,
                                        Body=dumps(plans_archivable_docs)
                                        )
        print (response)
```

Is there any anther more memory efficient option ?

Comment: Have you considered writing a separate JSON object per row, and then read a document at a time / _stream_ a line to S3 at a time?

Comment: yes ..Its kind of last option . I can fetch docs in batches and write them to multiple files.

Comment: If you're able to stream documents from your cursor, you can pipe that stream to S3.  I'll try to write a POC later when I have some time. There is the `ijson` library that allows to stream json

Answer (score 2):

A strategy to apply for large files in your scenario is to upload it in chunks to Amazon S3 bucket. 
You can make use of [`MultipartUpload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadComplete.html) API available in the `boto3` library. I suggest this way if you want to concatenate the chunks to a single file after uploading.

That explained you can implement a naive writer if you consider concatenating the chunks to not be important here. 
A naive writer that uploads documents in your collection in chunks could be written as follow.

> Note that you can improve on this to handle errors and perform retries. You can also run the uploads in the parallel.

```
import json
import io
import boto3
from pymongo import MongoClient

class ObjectChunkIO:

    def __init__(self, bucket, prefix):
        self.bucket = bucket
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.iterator = self.chunk_iterator()

    def next_chunk(self):
        return next(self.iterator)

    def chunk_iterator(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

### Uploading MongoDb collection as chunks to Amazon S3 bucket

```
class ObjectChunkWriter(ObjectChunkIO):

    def __init__(self, bucket, prefix, chunk_size=5e7):
        super().__init__(bucket, prefix)
        self.chunk_num = 0
        # the object size in bytes. defaults to 50MB
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size

    def _upload_buf(self, object_data):
        self.bucket.put_object(Body=object_data, Key=self.path())

    def chunk_iterator(self):
        while True:
            buffer = io.BytesIO()

            yield buffer

            buffer.close()

            self.chunk_num += 1

    def path(self):
        return '{prefix}.{0:03d}.json'.format(
            self.chunk_num, prefix=self.prefix)

    def write(self, cur):
        with self.next_chunk() as buf:

            for doc in cur:
                b_doc = json.dumps(doc).encode('utf-8')

                if buf.tell() + len(b_doc) > self.chunk_size:
                    self._upload_buf(buf.getvalue())
                    buf = self.next_chunk()

                buf.writelines([b_doc, b'\n'])

            self._upload_buf(buf.getvalue())
```

This can be used this way:

```
def get_collection():
    db_client = MongoClient()
    db = db_client.<database>

    return db.<collection>


def get_bucket():
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='<profile>')
    s3_resource = session.resource('s3')

    return s3_resource.Bucket('<bucket>')

def upload_in_chunks(cur, bucket):
    ''' Uploads documents returned in a MongoDb cur in chunks to S3 bucket
        Args:
            - cur: pymongo.cursor.Cursor
            - collection: s3.Bucket
    '''

    object_chunk_writer = ObjectChunkWriter(bucket,
                                            prefix='streaming/sample-output/chunk')

    object_chunk_writer.write(cur)


collection = get_collection()
cur = collection.find()
bucket = get_bucket()

upload_in_chunks(cur, bucket)
```

### Reading uploaded chunks into MongoDb collection

Reading the uploaded chunks is quite the easier part.

```
class ObjectChunkReader(ObjectChunkIO):

    def chunk_iterator(self):
        object_chunks = self.bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=self.prefix, MaxKeys=3)

        for object_summary in object_chunks:
            response = object_summary.get()
            body = response['Body']
            chunk_object = [json.loads(line) for line in body.iter_lines()]

            yield chunk_object

    def __iter__(self):
        for object_chunk in self.iterator:
            yield object_chunk

def write_objects_to_collection(bucket, collection):
    ''' Writes s3 objects to a MongoDb collection
        Args:
            - bucket: s3.Bucket
            - collection: pymongo.collection.Collection
    '''

    object_chunk_reader = ObjectChunkReader(bucket,
                                            prefix='streaming/sample-output/chunk')

    for object_chunk in object_chunk_reader:
        collection.insert_many(object_chunk)


collection = get_collection()
bucket = get_bucket()
write_objects_to_collection(bucket, collection)
```